# Publish to Windows Azure in debug or release mode

Tags: azure

I have an Windows Azure app (Asp Net Mvc 4).
And there is some ajax in this app. Some requests with simple in-memory server logic (no sql, no external web services).
When I run it locally in debug mode, it takes about 900 ms for ajax request to get a response.
Locally in release mode, it takes about 30 ms (It`s OK).
When I publish app to Azure it takes 450 ms for request to get a response. I try both debug mode and release, also cloud and local service configuration. In all cases it takes 450 ms.
Question: is there something that I did not take into account?

Comment: What is your service doing? Any external (I/O or network latency bound) operations? What are you measuring? Client round trip times or are you logging the service-side completion time of your operations?

Comment: It just takes some data from memory cache and return it. I measure client round trip times.

Comment: Have you tried to connect (via remote desktop) to another azure instance to eliminate network latency/bandwidth as a possible issue?

Comment: Thanks, Simon

It was network latency. Because servers are in east asia and i`m not there.

Comment: @VladimirMakhaev - It would be helpful, to others, if you provided a formal answer to your question and mark it as answered, rather than answering inside a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To properly diagnose the performance of your ASP.NET MVC application, you need to take in consideration:

1. The latency between your client computer and the server. Use the ping utility to measure that.
2. The time it takes to establish the HTTP and/or HTTPS connection.
3. The time spent waiting for other concurrent requests your browser may be issuing.
4. Data transfer time, both to send the request and to retrieve the response.
5. Queueing on the web server due to overload.
6. Time spent on the server actually processing the request. You can measure this with the [StopwatchAttribute](https://github.com/managedfusion/managedfusion-web/blob/master/src/Web/Mvc/StopwatchAttribute.cs) described in [this article](http://coderjournal.com/2010/10/timing-the-execution-time-of-your-mvc-actions/). Use the current code from GitHub though, because the code in the article is not compatible with ASP.NET MVC 3.

Tools like Chrome's and Internet Explorer's Developer Tools, Firefox's Firebug and Yahoo's YSlow can give you a greater insight on your application's performance.